# MariaDB JOIN based on JSON array

Tags: sql, json, mariadb, where-clause, mysql-json

I'm pretty sure this can be done, but after searching MariaDB docs, I'm not sure how.

I would like to return all items based on a `join_extract` search (I think).

These are the values to return from the `vendor_certs` table:

```
+----+-------------------+
| id | cert              |
+----+-------------------+
|  1 | Organic           |
|  2 | Kosher            |
|  5 | BRC               |
|  6 | SQF               |
|  7 | Halal             |
|  8 | ISO               |
|  9 | EPA               |
| 10 | NSF               |
| 11 | Walmart Certified |
| 12 | Target Certified  |
| 13 | FDA               |
+----+-------------------+
```

Based on a `SELECT` from the `vendor_key_value` table:

```
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+
| id | vendor_id | meta_key     | meta_value |
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+
| 28 |        12 | vendor_certs | ["9","13"] |
+----+-----------+--------------+------------+
```

I'm looking for the output to be:

`EPA, FDA`

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: I adjusted your tags and question title, since you are using MariaDB, not MySQL. Those two products have been slowly diverging since 2010, and you should think of them as different software now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, you can filter with `json_contains()`:

```
select vc.*
from vendor_certs vc
where exists (
    select 1
    from vendor_key_value vkv
    where 
        vkv.id = ? 
        and vkv.meta_key = 'vendor_certs' 
        and json_contains(vkv.meta_value, concat('"', cv.id, '"')
)
)
```

You can apply an aggregate function on the resultset if you like. Say you want a JSON array:

```
select json_arrayagg(vc.cert)
from vendor_certs vc
where exists (
    select 1
    from vendor_key_value vkv
    where 
        vkv.id = ? 
        and vkv.meta_key = 'vendor_certs' 
        and json_contains(vkv.meta_value, concat('"', cv.id, '"'))
)
```

Comment: I get "Variable name was expected. (near "?" at position 116)"

Comment: @DarioZadro: `?` represents a parameter to the query - I assumed that you wanted to to filter on a given `vendor_key_value` only. If that's not relevant, you can just remove that condition.

Comment: My bad. Now I get `json_contains  does not exist`

Comment: @DarioZadro: which version of MySQL are you running? `JSON_CONTAINS()` was added quite a while ago.

Comment: Looks like I might need a higher MariaDB version, currently 10.1.47

Comment: @DarioZadro: yes, this requires MariaDB 10.2.3: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_contains/. Manipulating JSON without JSON functions will be tedious. Any plans to upgrade?

Comment: Upgraded to 10.5 and your solution works great. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, this doesn't work. It's pulling extra results that are not part of `meta_key`

Comment: @DarioZadro: well, if there are several rows in `vendor_key_value` for a given `id`, then you need a filter on `meta_key`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'll still accept the answer from @GMB because it got me on the right track.

However, after some tinkering and reading docs on JSON functions, this was much easier to work with and understand for me.

```
SELECT cert
FROM vendor_certs
JOIN vendor_key_value
ON JSON_CONTAINS(vendor_key_value.meta_value, concat('"', vendor_certs.id, '"'))
WHERE meta_key = 'vendor_certs' AND vendor_id = 12
```

I don't know if the other answer is a faster query or has other benefits, but I hope my answer helps someone else that might get stuck on a similar JSON join.